# Error:Connection timed out: connect When Update into 3.0 Canary5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I try Update my Android Studio into **3.0 Canary5** and My Project Have Error:

```
Connection timed out: connect
```

Thank You for Helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found My Solution in [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#flavor_selection) and fix my Project

this problem happen when Gradle try to download version which is not Exist!? or Failed.

GoodLuck